# Bottom border wider than div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a theme for a blog right now and I want to separate individual posts with a thin line. Each post is centered and 800 pixels wide. So naturally,

```
.post {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 800px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Gives me a nice little border underneath the post.

However, because the post `<div>` itself is only 800 pixels wide, the border-bottom will also be `800` pixels wide and centered underneath the post. I'd love to have a little separator that goes across the whole screen without having to set the div's width to `100%`. Any ideas?

Comment: Show us your HTML, add link to fiddle or to zour page directly.

Comment: how about a simple `<hr>`?

Comment: add `display:inline-block;` and remove padding that cause overflow in element..

Answer (score 6):

You can do this if your `.post` is not positioned relative:

```css
html {
    width: 100%;
}

.post {
    background: cyan;
    margin: 40px auto 80px;
    width: 400px;
}

.post::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit perspiciatis ipsam necessitatibus repudiandae molestias soluta possimus rerum cum. Veritatis pariatur harum est assumenda nemo voluptas distinctio cum adipisci error voluptatem!</div>
<div class="post">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit perspiciatis ipsam necessitatibus repudiandae molestias soluta possimus rerum cum. Veritatis pariatur harum est assumenda nemo voluptas distinctio cum adipisci error voluptatem!</div>
```

> *See original [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/E2M6U/1/).*

Comment: The basic assumption is that this bottom border should take up 100% of the parent container.. whether it's body or any other.. so as long as .post element itself is not relative, this solution should work.

Comment: @TJ firstly I can't believe you just mentioned IE5 ;].. secondly you have a point.. I like your solution too (less css), but I like this solution because (less html) you won't have to remember to include <hr> after every post, and you would also need to stylize the margin for it in the css.. with this one, you just write your post and the style is done automatically with CSS.. separating style from structure as advised.

Comment: i hate ie 5,6,7,8,9.. just added for the sake of argument.. lol.. forget it :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of useing an border-bottom, use :after instead.

Example

```
.post {
       background: #fff;
       margin: 40px auto;
       width: 800px;
       padding-bottom: 40px;
       /*border-bottom: 1px solid grey;*/
    }
.post:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    height:0px;
    width:820px;
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
}
```

See the gained width and left positioning.

Comment: Why did anyone minus me? It is a solution, its not good, but it does solve whats asked for?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `<hr>` tag.

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/6GnsX/)

It'll create the little separator that goes across the whole screen without having to set the `<div>`'s width to `100%`. you don't have to worry about any positioning properties or browser support either.

### Update

If ancient browser support is not an issue, you can create a separator that covers the entire screen regardless of the width of container using `vw` unit and css pseudo elements as follows *(Assuming the element is centered horizontally)*:

html

```
<div class='demo'></div>
```

css

```
.demo {
 position:relative;
}
.demo::after {
 content:"";
 display:block;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 position:absolute;
 left:-50%;
 bottom:0;
 width:100vw;
 border-top:1px solid black;
}
```

### [Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/6GnsX/2/)